# how to modify the code when change the backend from theano to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backend, theano

Here is the code sample:
https://github.com/keiserlab/keras-neural-graph-fingerprint/blob/master/NGF/layers.py

in the beginning, it has

```
import theano.tensor as T
import keras.backend as K
```

However, I want to use tensorflow as backend. How can I modify the code?

Also, Later the programmer use some code like

```
# Set pad value and set subtensor of actual tensor
output = T.set_subtensor(output[:, :paddings[0], :], padvalue)
output = T.set_subtensor(output[:, paddings[1]:, :], padvalue)
output = T.set_subtensor(output[:, paddings[0]:x.shape[1] + paddings[0], :], x)
```

Do I need to also change this code since I change the backen?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to change all the Theano operations to TensorFlow. Your question is quite broad - what have you tried?

Comment: If you are looking to convert theano weights to tensorflow format, you can go through this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5374) where the users discuss in detail of how to accomplish it